# Double Integral involving modifed bessel function

Tags: special-functions, integral-transforms

I'm try to derive a closed form of the following double integral:
$\int\limits_0^x {\int\limits_0^x {{e^{ - {K_1}uv}}{I_0}\left( {2{K_1}\sqrt {uv} } \right)du} dv}$; where $K_1$ is a constant.
Do you have any suggestions?
Thank you very much.

Comment: Do you have some background for this question. Also (maybe related), why do you tag it with integral-transform.

Comment: My experience with integrals like this is that they have no "closed" form unless $x = \infty$, and that's for the single integral.

Comment: @rlgordonma: 2D and Bessel functions sometimes help each other...

Comment: @Fabian: I agree.  This case, however, is equivalent to an integral of a Bessel-Gaussian form.  With most special functions like this, unless the integration bounds are branch points or $\infty$, there is typically no closed form unless it is an antiderivative.

Comment: Still I would be interested where this integral comes from.

Comment: I found the solution from a reference paper, which is: A Double Integral Containing the Modified Bessel Function: Asymptotics and Computation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution from a reference paper, which is: A Double Integral Containing the Modified Bessel Function: Asymptotics and Computation.

http://www.ams.org/journals/mcom/1986-47-176/S0025-5718-1986-0856712-X/S0025-5718-1986-0856712-X.pdf

Comment: Nice find, but where is the particular integral the OP wanted?